# C++ - How to print a tuple consisting of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I need to print the vectors contained in Tuple "taborder".
Below code

```
std::vector<std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > taborder;

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    std::vector<int> id (i,5);
    std::vector<int> x (i,10);
    std::vector<int> y (i,15);
    taborder.push_back(std::make_tuple(id, x, y));
}

for(vector<tuple>::iterator iter = taborder.begin(); iter != taborder.end(); iter++){
cout << get<0>(*iter) << "\t" << get<1>(*iter) << "\t" << get<2>(*iter) << endl;
}
```

produces an error:

`type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'`|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up outer vector iteration and inner vectors one.

You can use **auto** feature from new standard to reduce naming bloat and use compiler to deduce exact type and for each loop to simplify code.

[Here](http://ideone.com/3FhRQ7) you can find working example of your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::vector<std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > taborder;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        std::vector<int> id (i,5);
        std::vector<int> x (i,10);
        std::vector<int> y (i,15);
        taborder.push_back(std::make_tuple(id, x, y));
    }

    for(auto & outer_vec_elem : taborder){
        auto & inner_vec0 = get<0>(outer_vec_elem);
        auto & inner_vec1 = get<1>(outer_vec_elem);
        auto & inner_vec2 = get<2>(outer_vec_elem);

        for(auto inner_vec_elem : inner_vec0){
            cout << inner_vec_elem << "\t";
        }
        for(auto inner_vec_elem : inner_vec1){
            cout << inner_vec_elem << "\t";
        }
        for(auto inner_vec_elem : inner_vec2){
            cout << inner_vec_elem << "\t";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you **didn't complete specify the type for your iterator**:

Either use `auto` or for pre C++11 compilers

`vector<tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > >::iterator`

Also within your main loop you have to **iterate over the inner vectors inside each tuple**.

In the following are more or less the variants you can use, depending on how you want your output:

**1. variant : tuple wise output  (assuming all vectors have the same size)**

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > taborder;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        std::vector<int> id (i,5);
        std::vector<int> x (i,10);
        std::vector<int> y (i,15);
        taborder.push_back(std::make_tuple(id, x, y));
    }

    for(vector<tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > >::iterator iter = taborder.begin(); iter != taborder.end(); iter++){
    // or  
    // for(auto iter = taborder.begin(); iter != taborder.end(); iter++){

        auto mytuple = *iter;

        // You have to iterate over all the inner vectors

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < get<0>(mytuple).size(); ++i ) {
            cout << get<0>(mytuple)[i] << "\t" << get<1>(mytuple)[i] << "\t" << get<2>(mytuple)[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. variant : each tuple vector** (as other ansers already show)

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > taborder;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        std::vector<int> id (i,5);
        std::vector<int> x (i,10);
        std::vector<int> y (i,15);
        taborder.push_back(std::make_tuple(id, x, y));
    }

    for(vector<tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > >::iterator iter = taborder.begin(); iter != taborder.end(); iter++){
    // or  
    // for(auto iter = taborder.begin(); iter != taborder.end(); iter++){

        auto mytuple = *iter;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < get<0>(mytuple).size(); ++i ) {
            cout << get<0>(mytuple)[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < get<1>(mytuple).size(); ++i ) {
            cout << get<1>(mytuple)[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;            

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < get<2>(mytuple).size(); ++i ) {
            cout << get<2>(mytuple)[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, your second proposition is more palatable given the vector size varies.